# Codename one Android Sidemenu

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to implement an Android style side menu and I'm having an issue implementing the rounded icon on top and labels below it before the sideCommands are added.

How do I implement this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Toolbar API which allows you to add components to the Sidemenu.

Have a look at [Flickr demo](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/blob/master/Flickr/src/com/codename1/demos/Flickr.java).

Instead of using `tool.addCommandToSideMenu(Command)` you should use `tool.addComponentToSideMenu(yourComponent, CommandToPerform)`

**Example:**

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
    //Store your commands before setting toolbar
    List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < f.getCommandCount(); i++) {
        cmds.add(f.getCommand(i));
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
    f.setToolBar(toolbar);
    Label lblTitle = new Label("My Form", "Title");
    lblTitle.setEndsWith3Points(false);
    toolbar.setTitleComponent(lblTitle);

    // Use your stored commands after setting toolbar
    for (Command cmd : cmds) {
        toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(cmd);
    }

    Container CustomContainer = ...
    toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(CustomContainer, new Command("") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //What CustomContainer should do (if any)
        }
    });
    f.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: i'm using the GUI builder for the app and i want to add a component on the top of the sidebar commands. Tried `f.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(CustomContainer); ` but i get a Null Pointer Exception because `f.getToolbar()` returns null

Comment: It would give you Exception, I will edit my answer to give you usage example.

Comment: I did add an example, check it out and mark as answer if it does help.

Comment: This works but it clears the commands that were added previously via the GUI builder thus forcing me to add all those commands to this new `toolbar` via code

Comment: I've edited my answer to include copying previous commands to Toolbar

Comment: Improved my answer, if commands are not stored before setting toolbar, they got lost.